# Error in trying to write $\bar{X}$ in R markdown

Tags: pdftex, pdf, r, rmarkdown

I want to write the distribution of the average of n i.i.D's. However I keep receiving the following error when I write the following in R markdown.

```
$$\bar{X}\sim N(\mu_X,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$$
```

Error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \bar allowed only in math mode.
```

I have installed tinytex in R, if there is a specific package I need to install please tell me :)

Edit: I have just noticed that when I output the document to an HTML document there is no error, however I only receive this error when I output to a pdf, if that helps.

Comment: Is there a reason for `$$` instead of `$`?

Comment: @Stephen It just lets me put it onto its own line

Comment: Can you get `$\bar{X}\sim N(\mu^{}_X,\sigma_{\!X}^2/n)$` to compile?

Comment: @Mico I had a space next to one of the $ signs which was causing the error, apologies

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because an input error, discovered by the OP, was the cause of the problem.